# Find differences in column headers between different csv files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, difference

I have a problem where my pandas joins are running into an error where certain headers cannot be found (in this case, the column 'Experience Score'). The error gets thrown but doesn't tell me which file is causing the error. I'm trying to reduce the headache of trying to workaround the issue, and want to find the actual files that are either missing the headers I need, or if the headers are the wrong dtype, etc.

To solve this, I am going through multiple csv files and trying to find the difference between the column headers in each file. Currently, this is my process:

```
def create_file_list(dir):
    # return a list of files for a directory specified in dir object
    return [os.path.join(dir, file) for file in os.listdir(dir)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dir = r'C:\Users\name\Documents\folder'

    # create a file list of all the files in the directory
    file_list = create_file_list(dir)

    # iterate over each file in the list, 
    # pull out the headers of each file, 
    # then compare if the headers are different from the desired header list (df)
    for path in file_list:
        try:
            data = pd.read_csv(path, dtype=str, header=2)
        except:
            data = pd.read_excel(path, dtype=str, header=2)
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Domain', 'Created Time', 'Experience Score'])
```

The pseudo code I want to apply next is seeing if the columns are different, to tell me which file(s) have different headers:

```
# find the file paths of files that have different headers from the df headers
if data.columns.difference(df.columns) > 0:
         print(path)
```

Currently, with data.columns.difference(df.columns), I get either outputs:

```
1) Index(['Vertical Type (Product)'], dtype='object')
2) Index([], dtype='object')
```

But these don't tell me which file(s) has the difference, and which file(s) are identical.

Ideally, I want output that says something to the effect of:

```
1) C:\Users\name\Documents\folder\file_1.csv : Index(['Vertical Type (Product)'], dtype='object')
2) C:\Users\name\Documents\folder\file_2.csv : Index([], dtype='object')
```

Comment: if you're joining on `Experience Score`, why not `if 'Experience Score' not in df.columns`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget great point, I think that might have solved the issue I was looking for:         if 'Experience Score' not in data.columns:
            print(path)